# Android Gradle 6.5.1 cannot find my uploaded public key for GPG verification

Tags: android, gradle, gnupg, pgp

I have submit my testing public key. When verifying my aar binary in Android, the key cannot be found in server.

jayce@Jayce ~ % gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --send-keys 24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E
gpg: sending key 07D519E4D7C4AD7E to hkp://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
jayce@Jayce ~ % gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --revc-keys 24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E
gpg: invalid option "--revc-keys"
jayce@Jayce ~ % gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E
gpg: key 07D519E4D7C4AD7E: "Jayce jayce@testing.com" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

In Android verification-metadata.xml:

```
 <key-servers>
      <key-server uri="hkp://keys.gnupg.net"/>
 </key-servers>

 <trusted-keys>
      <trusted-key id="24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E" group="com.jayce.testing"/>
 <trusted-keys>
```

Error:

```
artifacts failed verification:
Key 07D519E4D7C4AD7E (not found) couldn't be found in any key server so verification couldn't be performed

This can indicate that a dependency has been compromised. Please carefully verify the signatures and checksums.
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when searching, "0x" has to be added in front of HEX string. After the key got found at first time, then it will work.

same in website search, you have to add 0x to find the key.

http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?search=24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E&fingerprint=on&op=index

http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?search=0x24F7C6C5D7B6B147B1AB602807D519E4D7C4AD7E&fingerprint=on&op=index